# Prolog rule - False?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have facts:

```
/**--(course,time,location)--*/

ctl('course1', 'time1','location1').
ctl('course2', 'time1','location2').
ctl('course3', 'time2','location3').

/**--Lecturer,course-*/

lc('lecturer1','course1').
lc('lecturer2','course2').
lc('lecturer1','course3').
```

and my rule for lecturer's `schedule(course,time,location)` is:

```
schedule(Lecturer,C,T,L) :-
   lc(Lecturer,C),ctl(C,T,L).
```

If I do:
**?- schedule('lecturer1',C,T,L).** to check what is lecturer1's schedule,it will output 2 groups of answer,

but if I do: 
**?- schedule(Lecturer,C,'time1',_).** to check who is scheduled to teach what on time1, it will should "false" after output 2 groups of answer.

Does anyone how to fix the "false"?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to fix anything; the `false` simply means Prolog can't find any more solutions. It's harmless.